# Report can't view using jasper

Tags: java

I got this while Report viewing using jasper:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

where exactly my problem?

How could i solve this one, whereas i'm not getting error in my coding][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnNSR.png)

Comment: how your code looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very much descriptive but in general, You need to get a reference to your report by using :
`getClass().getResource("/testjasper/report1.jrxml")`

which will return a URL.

From memory, you should be able to `Jasper` a `InputStream`, this can be achieved by using `URL#openConnection`